# Удалить множество старых веток в Bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

У меня в Bitbucket-репозитории больше 300-х веток, большая часть из которых старые и ненужные. Удалять вручную их замучаешься.

Мне нужно удалить все ветки старше одного месяца (или хотя бы оставить 100 самых свежих). Ещё мне нужно сохранить некоторые ветки, например те, в которых встречается `release` и `develop`.

Это всё было бы удобно сделать через UI Bitbucket-а, просто выделить галочками нужные ветки и удалить, но я не нашёл такой возможности.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Несмотря на то, что есть и другие варианты решения этой проблемы, мне стало интересно попробовать решить эту проблему с помощью selenium. Если вам любопытно, что получилось в итоге, или не подходят другие варианты по каким-то своим причинам, то вот тут можно посмотреть результат:

https://github.com/globad/remove-old-branches

Все, что требуется, это клонировать [репозиторий](https://github.com/globad/remove-old-branches), загрузить нужную версию Chrome-webdriver, ввести несколько констант, таких как URL к вашему репозиторию, и запустить скрипт. Код достаточно простой, чтобы в нём разобраться. Если что, пишите комментарии / создавайте Issue.

Можно запускать на любой ОС, где присутствует Node.js (т.е. и на Windows).

Answer (score 1):

Есть [вот такое](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10325758/1991579), если через консоль (да, если не на Win), чтоб удалить ветки старше 1 месяца.

```
for k in $(git branch | sed /\*/d); do 
  if [ -n "$(git log -1 --before='1 month ago' -s $k)" ]; then
    git branch -D $k
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

раз пошла такая пьянка и подходят советы для операционной системы *gnu/linux*, то:

нарисовать там список с «галочками» не просто, а очень просто. с помощью программы [*whiptail*](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Bash_Shell_Scripting/Whiptail) или её «прародителя» — *dialog*. одна из них обязательно в системе имеется (а если и не имеется — так поставить тоже просто — и та и другая опакетированы во всех современных версиях дистрибутивов).

рисуем команду (программы *whiptail* и *dialog* в данном случае полностью взаимозаменяемы):

```
$ whiptail --checklist "some text" 20 60 10 $(git for-each-ref \
  --format='%(refname)' refs/remotes/origin | while read h; do \
  echo "${h##*/} {$h} OFF"; done) 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 | \
  xargs -r git push --delete origin
```

запустив её в каталоге с локальной копией хранилища, получим приблизительно такую картинку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

отметим галочками ненужные нам ветки `new1` и `new2` (поставить/убрать отметку — <kbd>пробел</kbd>, перемещение по списку — <kbd>↑</kbd>/<kbd>↓</kbd>) и, переместив фокус на кнопку `<ok>` (перемещение между элементами окна — <kbd>tab</kbd>):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

подтвердим выбор, нажав <kbd>enter</kbd>. окошко «закроется» и в терминале отобразится результат выполнения программы *git* с нужными нам параметрами:

```
To адрес-хранилища
 - [deleted]         new1
 - [deleted]         new2
```

т.е., отчёт об уничтожении веток `new1` и `new2` в удалённом хранилище (если, уже запустив диалог, вдруг передумаете что-нибудь удалять, то нажатие <kbd>enter</kbd> на кнопке `<cancel>` отменит проведение этой операции).